# VSIX: Steps to port from VS2017 to VS2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, visual-studio-2019

Microsoft broke the following code fragment for VS2019, which from VS2013 through VS2017 worked fine.

```
public sealed class MyVsix :
    AsyncPackage,
    IVsSolutionEvents3,
    IVsUpdateSolutionEvents,
    IDisposable
{    
    private IVsSolution solution = null;
    private uint _hSolutionEvents = uint.MaxValue;
    private uint _hcookieUpdateSolution = 0;

    protected override async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<ServiceProgressData> progress)
    {
        AdviseSolutionEvents();

        // When initialized asynchronously, the current thread may be a background thread at this point.
        // Do any initialization that requires the UI thread after switching to the UI thread.
        await this.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(cancellationToken);

        // If I understand the new design, add UI initialization tasks here.
    }

    private void AdviseSolutionEvents()
    {
        //UnadviseSolutionEvents();

        solution = this.GetServiceAsync(typeof(SVsSolution)) as IVsSolution;
        if (null != solution)
            _ = solution.AdviseSolutionEvents(this, out _hSolutionEvents);

        _ = ((IVsSolutionBuildManager)this.GetService(typeof(SVsSolutionBuildManager))).AdviseUpdateSolutionEvents(this, out _hcookieUpdateSolution);
    }
...
}
```

Visual Studio 2019 throws the following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1748  Cannot find the interop type that matches the embedded interop type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IAsyncServiceProvider'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Error   CS1748  Cannot find the interop type that matches the embedded interop type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Error   CS1748  Cannot find the interop type that matches the embedded interop type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IAsyncServiceProvider'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Error   CS1748  Cannot find the interop type that matches the embedded interop type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

Sadly, the Microsoft Visual Studio docs are incomplete and many of the interfaces dealing with VSIX for VS2019 do not exist and those that exist do not have examples. The docs refer to VS2017, which is of course no help, as things changed.

`IvsSolutionEvents` still exists as does `IVsSolutionEvents3`. The change from synchronous load to asynchronous load should have no bearing on hooking into events. The change occurs with tapping into the user interface (cross thread and all that).

Here is a hover to show the actual complaint for the first error.

[image: Tapping into IVsSolutionEvents Error in Visual Studio 2019 VSIX]

Here is the complaint for the second error, tapping into `IVsSolutionBuildManager`

[image: Tapping into IVsSolutionBuildManager Error in Visual Studio 2019 VSIX]

I did try a Google search, several times, and the results were less than stellar. Basically, there is little documentation for VSIX projects.

> We're no longer updating this content regularly. Check the Microsoft Product Lifecycle for information about how this product, service, technology, or API is supported.

Thoughts?

UPDATE #1

I just posted this question, however I just found this article, which states that the `GetService` method should not be used in Aync initialization events, so I am researching that now too.

[how to use asyncpackage to load vspackages in the background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-asyncpackage-to-load-vspackages-in-the-background?view=vs-2019)

UPDATE #2:
I changed the title from `VSIX: IvsSolution.AdviseSolutionEvents Changes for Visual Studio 2019`. I am getting towards a solution having already answered a few of my questions. As soon as I have my port working, I will post an answer. The question (and answer) is bigger than replacing the CSPROJ file.

Stay tuned.

Comment: Do you have a small repro project? or a step by step to create one?

Comment: @SimonMourier Create from VS2019 (Pro or above, I presume) a VSIX project. Unlike previous versions, the project template is minimal, but should suffice for your question. Name the project `MyVsix` if you want to conform to my sample. At that point, add the fragment above.

Comment: By default, a package is not loaded. Have you added anything to the class? Like PackageRegistration, AutLoad, etc.

Comment: @SimonMourier In previous versions that was not necessary, nor do I know what these methods are. The Microsoft created code is pathetic. Do you have a list of changes required to go from VS2017 to VS2019? To answer your question, no, as I never heard of these methods nor was it required.

Comment: I have started from scratch, added a ProvideAutoLoad (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-asyncpackage-to-load-vspackages-in-the-background?view=vs-2019) attribute to the class, changed your code to use async and I don't have any problem (I'm running off the latest VS 2019). You must use async everywhere today if you don't want any warnings. Old binary works as is, old source also works but with tons of warning but  someday, (next VS?) it won't anymore, yes. Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/raw/hCHqmMbN

Comment: @SimonMourier thank you, inching forward! 1) Your code behaves the same was as mine. The problem are multiple differences in the CSPROJ file. The easiest way is to create a new project and then add the old source files. That gets rid of the errors. Updating was not thorough.    2) How do I switch to the main UI thread?     3) Can I switch to the main UI thread in the Dispose() override? I have to call UnadviseSolutionEvents(), which require being called in the UI thread.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I changed the title of the question (and had intended to do that), as the real question is how to port a VSIX project from VS2017 to VS2019. I am compiling a list of actions. Yes, I sort of solved the first problem. The steps are more involved than replacing the CSPROJ file. Stay tuned. This question should hopefully be the web's port answer, as Microsoft did not bother with it, sadly.

Comment: Maybe you have another direction following [this document](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/how-to-upgrade-extensions-to-support-visual-studio-2019/) using VS2017. Since VS2019 sdk has some difference with VS2017 SDK, you can try upgrading VS2017 vsix to VS2019.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I do not follow your comment. I "upgraded" the project and Visual Studio did a pathetically poor job. The requirement is to replace the VSIX project file starting over again, update the manifest file, and then make other changes. I am working on those changes now, just I have other projects on my plate, not just VSIX.

Comment: Hi Sarah, have you tried to create a new vsix project in VS2019 and copy the code above into it, it builds well in my machine with VS2019 SDK.